# can't read bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I ran into this syntax

```
export ts=${2:-`date "+%s"`}
```

I know about `export` and `${2}`. I even understand `+%s`

what does it mean to add `:-` behind it?

googling these symbols is useless. where do you look up things like this?

Comment: You look in the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) or by executing the handy shell command `man bash`. In the latter case, you can search for a string using the `/` command, so typing `/:-` once `man bash` is executing  would take you directly to the answer to your question. I know reading documentation on your actual computer is old-fashioned, now that we have an infinitude of imprecisions on the world-wide web, but it still has its place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dash causes the expansion to be the value of the variable if it is defined, or the expansion of what follows if the variable is not defined.

Example:

```
AA=aa
echo ${AA:-11}
echo ${BB:-22}
```

Will produce the output:

```
aa
22
```

Because `AA` *is* defined and `BB` is not.

Comment: You can search on the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) for `:-` to find the documentation

Answer (score 2):

It means "If the second command line argument has not been passed to the program, use the following value":

```
`date "+%s"`
```

It is called "parameter substitution" and is documented [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html).

Comment: Note that the OP does not have the back ticks.

Comment: @Ziffusion I guess he has. It's just a formatting issue. Backticks are interpreted as a code portion in the SO syntax highliter.

Comment: thanks. I understand both answers. Not sure what's the discussion on backticks. I understand backticks to mean "execute" in bash. That was not a mistake, a SO notation, nor a typo.